# How to access and remove all unwanted objects in a matplotlib figure manually?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to understand the underlying concepts of matplotlib, especially [Axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html) and [Figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/figure_api.html). Therefore I am trying to plot two scatters and then remove any superfluous space (the red one below) by accessing different APIs & objects in the hierarchy.

Yet I fail to understand where the remaining red space is coming from. This is the code:

```py
# Random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

# Create a single Axes and preconfigure the figure with red facecolor.
# Then plot a scatter
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10,5), facecolor='r')
ax1 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='A', y='B', ax=axes[0])
ax2 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='B', y='A', ax=axes[1])

# Remove except the scatter
for a in [ax1, ax2]:
    a.set_xlabel(''), a.set_ylabel('')  # Remove x and y labels
    for loc in ['left', 'right', 'bottom', 'top']:
        a.spines[loc].set_visible(False)  # Remove spines
    a.set_xticks([], []),  a.set_yticks([], [])  # Remove ticks
    a.set_xmargin(0), a.set_ymargin(0)  # No margin beyond outer values
    
# On figure-level we can make it more tight
fig.tight_layout()
```

It produces the following figure:

[image: Output]

I saw that there is something like..

```py
a.set_axis_off()
```

.. but this doesn't seem to be the right solution. Somewhere there seems to be some kind of padding that remains. It doesn't look like it's from some X/Y axis as it's the same for all four edges in both subplots.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can set the position of a subolot in figure coordinates, e.g. `0, 0, 0.5, 1` and `0.5, 0, 0.5, 1`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Could you please point me to the API that you're referring to?

Comment: Good question. I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Two things are needed:
First we need to initialize the Figure with `frameon=False`:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(
    // ...
    frameon=False)
```

The space between the subplots can be removed using the subplot layout:

```py
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.0, hspace=.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the finest level of layout control, you can position your axes manually instead of relying on matplotlib to do it for you. There are a couple of ways of doing this.

One option is [`Axes.set_position`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_position.html)

```
# Random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

# Create a pair of Axes and preconfigure the figure with red facecolor.
# Then plot a scatter
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5), facecolor='r')
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='A', y='B', ax=axes[0]).set_position([0, 0, 0.5, 1])
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='B', y='A', ax=axes[1]).set_position([0, 0.5, 0.5, 1])
```

You could also use the old-fashioned [`Figure.add_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) method:

```
# Random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

# Create a pair of Axes and preconfigure the figure with red facecolor.
# Then plot a scatter
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), facecolor='r')
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='A', y='B', ax=fig.add_axes([0, 0, 0.5, 1]))
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='B', y='A', ax=fig.add_axes([0, 0.5, 0.5, 1]))
```